# Инструмент для подсчета количество запросов на сервер

Tags: android, android-studio, запрос

Нужен инструмент для подсчета количество запросов на сервер,  длительность прихода ответа,  если  такой инструмент у android studio ? (что то не могу найти, ddms - сложно в понимание) или надо подключать какой нибудь плагин? чем вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Fiddler не? http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что самое простое для этого http://facebook.github.io/stetho/